# Validate presence of embedded document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I would like to validate that at least one option has been entered when saving my event. Option is a embedded mongoid document. How can I do this?

```
class Event

  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :date, type: Date

  embeds_many :invitees, cascade_callbacks: true
  embeds_many :participants, cascade_callbacks: true
  embeds_many :comments, cascade_callbacks: true
  embeds_many :options, cascade_callbacks: true

  has_one :owner, :class_name => "User"

  validates :name, :date, :presence => true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, autosave: true, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participants, autosave: true, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, autosave: true, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invitees, autosave: true, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner, autosave: true, allow_destroy: true

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a custom validator.

```
validate :has_at_least_one_option

def has_at_least_one_option
    if options.empty?
        errors[:base] << "Please choose at least one option"
    end
end
```

The presence of an error will cause a call to `save` to return false and fail to save the model.